# (junit/mockito) thread.join() is completed before thread work is done?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

did some quick searching and wasn't able to come up with much. Here is some small example code

```
Map<String, Integer> valuesFromThread = new HashMap<>();
List<String> threads = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();

labels.add('hello1');
labels.add('hello2');
labels.add('hello3');

for (String l : labels)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() ->
    {
        valuesFromThread.put(l, 123);
    });
    t.start();
    threads.add(t);
}

// wait for work to complete
for (Thread t : threads.values())
{
    t.join();
}

if (labels.size() != presignedS3Urls.size())
{
    // throw error (never happens in practice)
}
```

Since in practice we wait for each thread to finish, guaranteeing that there is an entry in `valuesFromThread` for each thread, therefore each label.

However when I use this method in a unit test, it seems like the work from the thread is never actually executed, or at least not before we do the check at the bottom.

Note, this code is nested within a method I need to test, so I am not actually needing create a mock scenario equivalent to the above which tests something similar, I need this logic to be able to be testable via the outer method without changing any of it.

Is there any way to resolve this?

I have not found any resources on this issue, so have not been able to try anything yet.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a minimal, runnable example which reproduces the problem.

Comment: I thought it was clarified above that this is code that is run within a method I am trying to test with junit/mockito. Is there some other way I can convey this?

Comment: There's no `values` method on `List` so clearly this is not the code that's run.

Comment: Yea.  This is clearly not real code.  Not what you are running.  Not something that we can run.  But I notice that the code is updating a HashMap from multiple threads without synchronization.  That's not thread-safe, and could result in all sorts of oddities.  If you took the time to create a REAL minimal reproducible example, we could maybe figure out what you are actually doing wrong ... at least in the minrep.  Please read [How do I create a Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `HashMap` is not thread-safe. If you modify it from multiple threads, the result is undefined (could be wrong, could crash, could deadlock, …). Don't modify non-thread-safe data types from multiple threads.